# Querying for Norwegian born people results in undefined namespace prefix

Tags: java, sparql, jena, dbpedia

I'm trying to make a basic DBpedia application (just for testing). When I use this query:

```
SELECT ?person WHERE {
  ?person dbo:birthPlace:Norway ?person
}
```

I get the following message:

> SPARQL compiler, line 6: Undefined namespace prefix at '' before '}'

Could anybody perhaps tell me what I am doing wrong? It works on the DBpedia query tester.

#### Edit: Java Code from Pastebin

```java
package jena_test;

import java.io.Writer;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QuerySolution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;

public class Dbpedia {

    String test = "123"; 
    static String sparqlQueryString="PREFIX dbo:<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> "
            + "SELECT ?person "
            + "WHERE { ?person dbo:birthPlace dbo:Norway } ";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub





        Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
                         Query query = QueryFactory.create(sparqlQueryString);

                         QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://dbpedia.org/sparql", sparqlQueryString);


                         try {
                             com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();
                             for ( ; results.hasNext() ; )
                         {
                             QuerySolution soln = results.nextSolution() ;
                             String x = soln.get("Concept").toString();

                             System.out.print(x +"\n");


                         }

                         }

                         finally { qexec.close() ; }

                         }

    }
```

Comment: Reasons for closing questions include “questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself,” and 
“questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.” I've added the Java code that you linked to in one of the comments, but it also would be nice if you can explain what you mean by “it works on the DBpedia query tester,” as pasting your query into http://dbpedia.org/sparql

Comment: produces the error “Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 4: Undefined namespace prefix at 'dbo' before ':Norway'”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't get your example to work on dbpedia and assume you meant to define the dbo namespace somewhere because it complains about not knowing what dbo is.

For example

```sql
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
SELECT ?person WHERE { ?person dbo:birthPlace dbpedia:Norway }
```

Which works. But does it return what you want?

Comment: Thank you so much. I believe that fixed the query, as I am no longer receiving error. However, I am still getting no output, could you please check my code?

http://pastebin.com/kDM5zqV9

Answer (score 3):

As [KevinY's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18430179/1281433) pointed out, you need to define the namespaces that you use.  On [the public DBpedia SPARQL endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql), a number of namespaces are predefined for you, including `dbpedia-owl:` and `dbpedia:`.  Using those, your query should be something like the following.  (I've included a `limit 50` so as to reduce the load that people clicking on the link impose on DBpedia.)

```
select ?person where {
  ?person dbpedia-owl:birthPlace dbpedia:Norway .
}
limit 50
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?person%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20?person%20dbpedia-owl:birthPlace%20dbpedia:Norway%20.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alimit%2050&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

In a comment on KevinY's answer, you linked to some pastebin code (but really, all relevant code should be included in the question;  please update your question!), where the query is defined as

```java
   static String sparqlQueryString="PREFIX dbo:<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> "
                    + "SELECT ?person "
                    + "WHERE { ?person dbo:birthPlace dbo:Norway } ";
```

which, after some string concatenation, is:

```
PREFIX dbo:<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
SELECT ?person 
WHERE { ?person dbo:birthPlace dbo:Norway }
```

which is *not* the same as the code that KevinY posted.  Notice that in the working queries, `birthPlace` is prefixed by `dbpedia-owl:`, i.e., the namespace of the ontology, whereas `Norway`, which is a simple DBpedia resource, is prefixed by `dbpedia:`.  That means that the IRIs in your query are very different from the ones in the working queries.  The working query that I presented produces plenty of results.  In fact, a modified version:

```
select count(?person) where {
  ?person dbpedia-owl:birthPlace dbpedia:Norway .
}
```

indicates that DBpedia contains 1694 known people who were born in Norway.